# Meaning of < > symbol in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I came across a mysql query which is

```
SELECT P.pid FROM Parts P WHERE P.color<> 'blue'
```

I dont understand the meaning of `<>` symbol in the query.I have never seen such a symbol in mysql.

And the query in which this subquery is embedded is

```
SELECT S.sname
    FROM Suppliers S
        WHERE S.sid NOT IN (SELECT C.sid
                            FROM Catalog C
                            WHERE C.pid NOT IN (SELECT P.pid  
                                                FROM Parts P
                                                WHERE P.color<> 'blue'))
```

And the tables are as follows --

```
Suppliers(sid:integer, sname:string, city:string, street:string)
Parts(pid:integer, pname:string, color:string)
Catalog(sid:integer, pid:integer, cost:real)
```

Can someone explain the use of this symbol ?

Comment: `<>` is the same as the `!=` symbol, it means "not equals".  For reference, there's also the `<=>` operator which means "NULL-safe" equals (comparing with NULL will return a boolean with "NULL-safe", otherwise it'd return NULL).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the not equal operator. It is same as `!=`

Answer (score 2):

It is 'not equal' some SQL versions it is '!=' instead of '<>'.